# How can I change the mouse settings?

Tags: fable-anniversary

I recently bought Fable Anniversary for PC and I was able to customize the keyboard settings however I couldn't find an option to rebind the mouse keys.

I don't like how you need the mouse for blocking and running, since these are essential abilities in the game, and it feels kinda weird to run with rightclick and block with the mouse wheel.

Is there any way I can change the mouse bindings?

Comment: You can if you're using a Razer mouse. Some other mouse manufacturers also come with software that allows you to remap/rebind keys/buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your mouse keybindings in the Keyboard options in the options menu. The section for the mouse should be at the top.

The problem is that it is only possible to put two actions on the same key only if one of the actions has the key assigned by default. But I would still recommend having only one action per key to avoid conflicts in the game code and also to be able to do distinct actions

I couldnt find the file that saves the current keybinding to make it easier to edit it (well, I found one but changing the value in the file doesnt not change it in the game).

Comment: Oh it seems they just added it with todays patch `Added more options to the keyboard remapping – you can now remap mouse controls` thanks for the answer anyways ;)

Comment: @Jutschge Haha, you should consider the fact that they might be reading your mind :P